# Libreoffice classes not available in java code

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, libreoffice

1.Added to build.gradle
implementation group: 'org.libreoffice', name: 'libreoffice', version: '7.0.0'

2.'Refresh gradle' project in Eclipse

3.Jar is available local[image]

4.Adding them manually seems to work:
import com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap;

Bootstrap.bootstrap();

But classes are not accessible in code with code completion

Comment: Please share the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your **Type Filters** preference page for **Java**. `com.sun` was originally only present in the Java Runtime, and not meant for application use, so filtered out.